# How do I declare a method as "friend"?

Tags: c++

Basically I have 2 classes under a namspace, and I want to give one of the methods of one class (call it `B::fun`) access to the private member of the other class (call it `class A`). However, I can't seem to get it to work. Here is a simple example that illustrates the problem:

```
namespace ABC // this could be global too
{
    class A;

    class B
    {
    public:
        int fun(A member);
    };

    class A
    {
    public:
        friend int B::fun(A member);

    private:
        int aint;
    };

    int B::fun(A member)
    {
        return member.aint; // error: member ABC::A::aint is inaccessible
    }
}
```

Why do I get this error?

**NOTE: Seems to be a compiler issue (using VC++ 11).**

Comment: It's private thats why its telling you its inaccessible

Comment: @aaronman note that I am trying to declare the method as a `friend` of `A`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually, with both G++ 4.8.1 and CLang++ 3.3 I'm getting an error in the `friend` line:

**g++**: `error: 'int ABC::B::fun(ABC::A)' is private`

**clang++**: `error: friend function 'fun' is a private member of 'ABC::B'`

That is, the error is that `ABC::B::fun()` is private, so the friend declaration fails, and then the line you signaled fails as a consequence.

This happens because simply you cannot make a friend that you cannot access.

The solution is to make `ABC::B::fun()` public, or make friend the whole `B`, or something similar.

By the way, the namespace has nothing to do with your error, but IMO it would be clearer if your friend declaration were simply:

```
friend int B::fun(A member);
```

as you are already inside namespace `ABC`.

Comment: The friendship isn't mutual :(

Comment: Ok, I've made the friend declaration public and removed the explicit namespacing, but I'm still getting the error (see adjusted version in OP). Any ideas?

Comment: @aaronman: I know, but if `A` declares `B` as friend, then any member function of `B` will be able to access `A::aint`, even if it is private.

Comment: @ausairman: No, no, you changed nothing. It does not matter if the friend declaration is in the public or the private section of the class. The problem is that `int fun(A)` is private _inside_ class `B`. My suggestion was to add `public:` to class `B`.

Comment: @ausairman: Weird. That exact code compiles without any complaint in both my compilers. What compiler (and version) are you using?

Comment: @ausairman: It may be a compiler bug. I've tested in [a VC++ online compiler](http://rise4fun.com/Vcpp/ud3) and it did compile.

Answer (score 2):

Change your friend declaration inside `A`

```
class A {
    friend class B;
    int aint;
};
```

Alternatively, to only friend the single method, you need to make `A` a friend of `B` since the method you're `friend`ing is private. Or you could make `fun(A)` public.

```
namespace ABC
{
    class A;

    class B
    {
        friend class A;
        int fun(A member);
    };

    class A
    {
        friend int B::fun(A);
        int aint;
    };

    int B::fun(A member)
    {
        return member.aint;
    }
}
```

Comment: @ausairman then you will need to make class `A` a friend of `B` since `fun(A)` is private. I'll edit my answer to include that.

Comment: I've already tried making `A::fun` public and I'm still getting the error anyway...

Comment: Still gives the same error for me... Obviously this is a VC++ problem... Thanks for the help though I'll take it up with Microsoft.